# error in apache at the staring of the computer

Tags: java, tomcat

i have windows vista and jdk_1.6 in my system. when i started the system i am not able to do the services of the tomcat. i can run my jsp files but can't run servlet files how it is done i don't know? i can run the servlet prog. in netbeans but can't at notepad.

please reply me.............!

Comment: Your question is not clear. you can run JSPs - so do you want to learn more starting up Tomcat along with Windows? or how to run servlets?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you didn't install it as a Windows Service, or didn't set the service to be Automatic starting?

See the [Tomcat Windows Service HOWTO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html).